# Change Toolbar button backcolor

Tags: vb6, toolbar, backcolor

Is is possible to change the backcolor of a button in vb6 toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

K.,
           [Refer this url](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=381167),in this they clearly showed to change the tool bar button back color

Comment: This is for changing the backcolor of the toolbar, I want to change the backcolor of a button placed on the toolbar.